# how to get list of data and return as like a model in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

My code is below getting list of data from mysql, I got this data here but I can't received in controller?

```
public static ReportViewModel GetReportList(string refno)
{
    ReportViewModel reportModel = null; 

    DataTable dt = DataAccessLayer.FillData_table("select newmembership.name,concat(newmembership.addr1,', ',newmembership.addr2,)  where newmembership.enrolledby='" + refno + "' and newmembership.m_status!='D' and newmembership.fm_type='PM' and newmembership.enrollmentno!='';");

    List<object> resultsrow = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList<object>();
    resultsrow = reportModel.resultsrow;

    return reportModel;
}
```

Comment: we will need controller code to have more context please

Comment: Try calling this method with `refno = " 1 or 1 = 1; --"`. There's a thing called parameterized queries, see how they work.

Comment: [HttpPost, Route("getReport")]
        public ResponseModel GetReportList(ReportViewModel reportModel)
        {
            var data = profileBusiness.GetReportList(reportModel);
         //   List<object> resultshow = profileBusiness.GetReportList(reportModel);

            return new ResponseModel()
            {
                HttpStatus = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Success = data != null,
                Message = data == null ? "No Data" : "",
                Result = data
            };
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are getting NullPointerException in your GetReportList method as you are not initializing reportModel. Please try this:

```
public static ReportViewModel GetReportList(string refno)
{
    ReportViewModel reportModel = new ReportViewModel(); // reportModel instance is created here.
    DataTable dt = DataAccessLayer.FillData_table("select newmembership.name,concat(newmembership.addr1,', ',newmembership.addr2,)  where newmembership.enrolledby='" + refno + "' and newmembership.m_status!='D' and newmembership.fm_type='PM' and newmembership.enrollmentno!='';");
    reportModel.resultsrow = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList<object>();
    return reportModel;
}
```

If you could show us ReportViewModel definition and the place where you are invoking GetReportList then we could help further.

Comment: [HttpPost, Route("getReport")]
        public ResponseModel GetReportList(ReportViewModel reportModel)
        {
            var data = profileBusiness.GetReportList(reportModel);
         //   List<object> resultshow = profileBusiness.GetReportList(reportModel);

            return new ResponseModel()
            {
                HttpStatus = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Success = data != null,
                Message = data == null ? "No Data" : "",
                Result = data
            };
        }                          this is my controller code i got null data?

Comment: above the comment that is my controller code , i got null data values

Comment: i got the values but its has print double time

Comment: then I would first execute database query for that refno and see how many records are there in database. You need to edit your description whic show us the methods that involve in this path of execution.

Answer (score 0):

i got double values how to fix this

```
{
    "Result": {
        "resultsrow": [
            {
                "RowError": "",
                "RowState": 2,
                "Table": [
                    {
                        "refno": "091271788888",
                        "name": "S Santhosh kumar",

                    },
                    {
                        "refno": "0912717006555",
                        "name": "ggg",

                    }
                ],
                "ItemArray": [
                    "091271788888",
                    "S Santhosh kumar",

                ],
                "HasErrors": false
            },
            {
                "RowError": "",
                "RowState": 2,
                "Table": [
                    {
                        "refno": "091271788888",
                        "name": "S Santhosh kumar",

                    },
                    {
                        "refno": "0912717006555",
                        "name": "ggg",

                    }
                ],
                "ItemArray": [
                    "0912717006555",
                    "ggg",

                ],
                "HasErrors": false
            }
        ]
    },
    "Message": "",
    "Success": true
}
```